# How to add Linkedin connections in the "People you may know" section faster with the help of a script?

Tags: javascript, console, linkedin-api

I'd like to ask why this code isn't working on Linkedin in this page https://www.linkedin.com/people/pymk/hub using the browser Console

```
setInterval(function() { var connectBtns = document.getElementsByClassName(‘bt-request-buffed’);
for(var i =0; i < connectBtns.length; i++) { console.log(connectBtns[i].parentNode.children[0].children[1].children[0].children[0].textContent);
connectBtns[i].click()}}, 500);
```

Is it because of the change in the class name? Since the class name has been changed from "bt-request-buffed" to "bt-request-buffed buffed-blue-bkg-1"

I have been using this recently before I found the first code

```
javascript:var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('bt-request-buffed buffed-blue-bkg-1'); 
for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) 
{ inputs[i].click(); }
```

But I hate the fact that I have to scroll until there is nothing pops so that I can apply the code into the address bar and let the code do the work so I tried the first code instead but it isn't working

I would also really appreciate it if you could help me create a code that automatically clicks on the Connect button until the very bottom of the page without scrolling and stuffs! I only started learning to code recently so.... Please help and thanks ahead!

Answer (score 3):

I just made a great working code to send out invites. You can also check out my video that explains how to use it. (works on the new interface of LinkedIn)
http://www.webiummedia.com/?mod=linkedin

Copy past this in the network page console

```
var mutual = 10; // You can change this number if you do not wish to send invites to accounts that has a number of mutual connexions below this number
var blockNoPhoto = 1; // Don't send invitations to accounts without a profile picture (1 to activate, 0 to deactivate)
var occKeywords = ""; // Add only accounts with a specific keyword in the occupation title (Empty "" to add all) Ex: Recruter,CEO,PHP,Programmer
var dismiss = 0; // Dismiss contacts that where not added (1 to activate, 0 to deactivate)
$.getScript('https://www.webiummedia.com/linkedin.js?v=2');
```

Comment: Made a few updates to make it work for recruiter accounts. Let me know if you encounter any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [Patrick Simard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2157510/patrick-simard)'s answer I developed my own little js script, to run on the 'My Contacts' page, that **doesn't add\invite** the names in the People You May Know Section; it **just filters them** based on key terms of your choosing and optionally also on a min number of mutual connections. Note, both a positive or negative search is possible: (code available on [GitHub](https://github.com/nkatz01/JavaScript-Exercises/blob/master/filterPplYouMayKnow.js))

P.S. if someone could improve it so that it doesn't run again (it just waits or something) if more names aren't loaded, its efficiency would be massively improved. I couldn't be bothered any longer.

```
var mutual = 4;
var occKeywords = "myWorkPlaceName, myUniversityName";
var posSearch = false;

function scrollDown() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
}

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function filterPpl(p) {
    section = document.getElementsByClassName("relative pb2");
    pplUMayKnowElems = section[0].getElementsByClassName("ember-view display-flex ");
    noOfPplUMayKnow = pplUMayKnowElems.length;
    occk = occKeywords.trim().split(",");
    for (var i = noOfPplUMayKnow-1; i >= p; i--) {
        var removed = false;
        if (pplUMayKnowElems[i] != undefined) {
            occupation = pplUMayKnowElems[i].getElementsByClassName("discover-person-card__occupation")[0].innerText;
            con = pplUMayKnowElems[i].getElementsByClassName("member-insights__reason")[0].innerText.trim().split(" ")[0];
            name = pplUMayKnowElems[i].getElementsByClassName("discover-person-card__name")[0].innerText;
            if (new RegExp(occk.join("|"), 'i').test(occupation) == !posSearch || (posSearch && !/[a-zA-Z]/g.test(occupation))) {
                pplUMayKnowElems[i].parentNode.removeChild(pplUMayKnowElems[i]);
                removed = true;
            }
            if (!removed && Number(con) != NaN && con < mutual) {
                pplUMayKnowElems[i].parentNode.removeChild(pplUMayKnowElems[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    sleep(5000).then(() => {
        if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
            showMorePplBtn = section[0].getElementsByClassName("artdeco-button artdeco-button--muted artdeco-button--1 artdeco-button--full artdeco-button--secondary ember-view");
            showMorePplBtn[0].click();
            scrollDown();
            filterPpl(noOfPplUMayKnow)
        } else {
            filterPpl(0)
        }
    });
}
filterPpl(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Source code](https://gist.github.com/maksii/e028dc8de7d42f12305911e53679d807)

I have updated script with some new features and changes like auto-refresh and check for already added users(click hide rather then add). Same use - just copy-paste in console and leave tab for some time.

to fix initial problem
change `connectBtns[i].parentNode.children[0].children[1].children[0].children[0].textContent` to

```
 connectBtns[i].parentNode.getElementsByClassName("name")[0].textContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it, Please use below code and keep scrolling page(used with chrome developer tool console):

```
setInterval(function () {
var connectBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('bt-request-buffed buffed-blue-bkg-1');
for (var i = 0; i < connectBtns.length; i++) {
    console.log( connectBtns[i].parentNode.getElementsByClassName("name")[0].textContent);
    connectBtns[i].click()
}}, 500);
```

Answer (score -1):

I need this fixed to, I am not sure why it stopped working

This almost works but it gets a textcontent error.

```
setInterval(function () {
    var connectBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('bt-request-buffed buffed-blue-bkg-1');
    for (var i = 0; i < connectBtns.length; i++) {
        console.log(connectBtns[i].parentNode.children[0].children[1].children[0].children[0].textContent);
        connectBtns[i].click()
    }
}, 500);
```